# g++ -O3 creates strange instructions for loop - two versions with the same asm

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization

I'm writing some codes for numerical computation using c++. I need to write code very carefully to help compiler to generate good instructions. Then, I find some things strange for g++ 9.2 with -O3 flag. I am not an expert of assemble, So I need someone to help me or point out where I am wrong.

Full codes can be found here https://godbolt.org/z/fyuYtq . I copy and paste the key snippet here

```cpp
void sum_twopointer(Elem *p1, Elem *p2, ptrdiff_t stride, ptrdiff_t start, ptrdiff_t end) {

    Elem sm = 0;
    for(auto i = start;i != end; ++i) {
        p1[0] = p2[0] + p2[0];
        p1 += stride;
        p2 += stride;
    }

}
```

It is compiled with `g++ -O3`. The version of g++ is 9.2. The assemble code is

```
sum_twopointer(double*, double*, long, long, long):
  cmp rcx, r8
  je .L32
  lea r9, [0+rdx*8]
  xor eax, eax
  cmp rdx, 1
  jne .L36
.L34:
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
  add rcx, 1
  addsd xmm0, xmm0
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+rax], xmm0
  add rax, r9
  cmp r8, rcx
  jne .L34
.L32:
  ret
.L36:
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
  add rcx, 1
  addsd xmm0, xmm0
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+rax], xmm0
  add rax, r9
  cmp r8, rcx
  jne .L36
  ret
```

As my understanding, the compiler is trying to do some optimization for the special case that stride is just 1, **so it create a new branch for the case that stride==1, but it doesn't do anything further. Note that the codes following the .L34 are just identical to those following .L36** .

I have done some benchmarks for this. The performance for stride=1 and stride=2, are list in the following.  The code is there https://gist.github.com/lhprojects/dac3a9fcf15bd5b1ec365ba6a87c679d

```
g++ -O2
---------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                     Time             CPU   Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------
BM_twopointer/8192/1       3743 ns         3742 ns       185062      stride=1
BM_twopointer/8192/2       1980 ns         1980 ns       328523      stride=2

g++ -O3
---------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                     Time             CPU   Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------
BM_twopointer/8192/1       5006 ns         5001 ns       120725      stride=1
BM_twopointer/8192/2       2043 ns         2041 ns       333914      stride=2
```

Anyway, for stride=1, performance get worse with -O3 compared to -O2. I want to know what happend to my code. Did I trigger some undefined behavior in c++? Or simply, there is a defect in code optimization in g++. (I am sorry if my English writing let you feel very confused.)

Comment: The optimization flag that is to blame is `-fversion-loops-for-strides` which is by default enabled with `-O3`. You can disable it with `-fno-version-loops-for-strides` after `-O3`. I don't know why it applies the loop versioning even if there is no benefit to it.

Comment: Not really an answer to the code above: But how the code performs, relays on many factors and it is not always easy to predict why code runs faster/slower with different compile options and why `O2` and `O3` do not always have the expected result. While compilers do an incredible optimization job they are not always correct, but an arbitrary benchmark might also perform differently than a real live use case, so it is hard to tell if the compiler is really wrong.  And interesting talk about that is [StrangeLoop "Performance Matters" by Emery Berger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-TLSBdHe1A)

Comment: @t.niese thank you for your comment. I agree that more optimization flags/higher optimization level will not always generate better codes. We have infinite situations. But I think here the defect in code is some what obviously. Two branchs are the same codes. It is too weired, I think.

Comment: @walnut thank you for your comment. I learned a useful trick now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the compiler needs to know that p1 and p2 don't overlap ... declaring them as __restrict pointers should allow the compiler to actually utilize the simd instructions.  It does seem odd to me that it would create a special case for stride==1, but then not do anything with that knowledge.

Comment: Just now, I added __restrict for p1 and p2, but it seems nothing changed. See https://godbolt.org/z/7Rqvna . And I think it is still safe to replace r9 register with literal '8', even if two pointers overlap.

Answer (score 0):

> As my understanding, the compiler is trying to do some optimization for the special case that stride is just 1, so it create a new branch for the case that stride==1, but it doesn't do anything further.

Retesting showed that the problem is fixed since GCC 13.1. Thus, it's likely a bug or at least a technical limitation in previous GCC versions.

Using the following code as a test:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef double Elem;

void sum_twopointer(Elem * __restrict  p1, Elem *__restrict p2, ptrdiff_t stride, ptrdiff_t start, ptrdiff_t end) {

    Elem sm = 0;
    for(auto i = start;i < end; ++i) {
        p1[0] = p2[0] + p2[0];
        p1 += stride;
        p2 += stride;
    }

}
```

In GCC 12.3, `-fversion-loops-for-strides` generates the following code. GCC attempts to detect whether the array has stride-1 access and generates a separate loop, but this "fast path" loop is identical to the fallback loop, and it doesn't do any optimization.

This is the case for both SSE and AVX (enabled with `-march=native`), even under `-Ofast`.

```
sum_twopointer(double*, double*, long, long, long):
  cmp rcx, r8
  jge .L1
  lea r9, [0+rdx*8]
  xor eax, eax
  cmp rdx, 1
  jne .L4
.L3:
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
  add rcx, 1
  addsd xmm0, xmm0
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+rax], xmm0
  add rax, r9
  cmp r8, rcx
  jne .L3
.L1:
  ret
.L4:
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
  add rcx, 1
  addsd xmm0, xmm0
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+rax], xmm0
  add rax, r9
  cmp r8, rcx
  jne .L4
  ret
```

However, in GCC 13.1, the stride-1 loop now uses a hardcoded offset `8` as designed:

```
sum_twopointer(double*, double*, long, long, long):
  cmp rcx, r8
  jge .L1
  xor eax, eax
  cmp rdx, 1
  jne .L12
.L3:
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
  add rcx, 1
  addsd xmm0, xmm0
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+rax], xmm0
  add rax, 8
  cmp r8, rcx
  jne .L3
.L1:
  ret
.L12:
  sal rdx, 3
.L4:
  movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
  add rcx, 1
  addsd xmm0, xmm0
  movsd QWORD PTR [rdi+rax], xmm0
  add rax, rdx
  cmp r8, rcx
  jne .L4
  ret
```

Comment: Still a useless optimization: `add rax, 8` isn't faster than `add rax, rdx`.  (P6-family register-read stalls could be a factor on decade-old CPUs, although not in this particular loop since it doesn't read many "cold" registers.)   And still missing the opportunity for auto-vectorization with stride=1, doing 2 or 4 doubles per vector.  So yes the loops are different, but no the bug isn't fixed; it's only worth versioning this loop for auto-vectorization.

Comment: Using `unsigned` instead of `double` doesn't help either.  https://godbolt.org/z/hfofd35W7  But manually doing loop versioning in the source `if( stride == 1 ) ... else ...` gets auto-vectorized code doing 8 `unsigned` left-shifts at once.  (Even if you use the same loop in both sides, constant propagation works in the side of the `if` that knows `stride==1`)